# Как правильно использовать analizer для ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Коллеги. Я использую 5.4.3 и [analysis-morphology 5.4.3](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology)

```
POST /categories/_close
PUT categories/_settings
{"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_search_analyzer" : {
                    "type": "custom",
                       "tokenizer" : "standard",
                       "filter" : ["lowercase", "search_synonym","russian_morphology", "english_morphology", "ru_stopwords", "russian"]
                  }
             },
          "filter" : {
                "search_synonym" : {
                    "ignore_case" : "true",
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : ["пончо,накидка"]
                 },
                "ru_stopwords" : {
                    "type" : "stop",
                    "stopwords" : "а,без,более,бы,был,была,были,было,быть,в,вам,вас,весь,во,вот,все,всего,всех,вы,где,да,даже,для,до,его,ее,если,есть,еще,же,за,здесь,и,из,или,им,их,к,как,ко,когда,кто,ли,либо,мне,может,мы,на,надо,наш,не,него,нее,нет,ни,них,но,ну,о,об,однако,он,она,они,оно,от,очень,по,под,при,с,со,так,также,такой,там,те,тем,то,того,тоже,той,только,том,ты,у,уже,хотя,чего,чей,чем,что,чтобы,чье,чья,эта,эти,это,я,a,an,and,are,as,at,be,but,by,for,if,in,into,is,it,no,not,of,on,or,such,that,the,their,then,there,these,they,this,to,was,will,with"
                 }
           }
    }
   }
   },
   "mappings": {
    "mydoc_data": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_search_analyzer"
                  },
                  "description": {
                "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_search_analyzer"
                  }
             }
         }
   }
  }
POST /categories/_open
```

Результат `"acknowledged": true`
Ищу вот так:

```
GET /categories/_search/
{
    "query":{
    "match": {
        "_all": "накидка"
    }
  }
}
```

"накидка" - не находит
"накидки" - находит

Документы, по которым ищу:

```
{
"took": 23,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 11,
"successful": 11,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 5.8937645,
    "hits": [
      {
          "_index": "categories",
        "_type": "categories",
        "_id": "7672",
        "_score": 5.8937645,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Накидки",
          "code": "nakidki",
          "parent_id": 7668,
          "lft": 15343,
          "rgt": 15344,
          "updated_at": "2017-07-04 11:40:43",
          "created_at": "2017-07-04 11:40:43",
          "id": 7672
        }
      },
      {
          "_index": "categories",
        "_type": "categories",
        "_id": "5682",
        "_score": 5.115262,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Чехлы и накидки на сиденья",
          "code": "chehlyi-i-nakidki-na-sidenya",
          "parent_id": 5676,
          "lft": 11363,
          "rgt": 11364,
          "updated_at": "2017-07-04 11:37:34",
          "created_at": "2017-07-04 11:37:34",
          "id": 5682
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В _all объединяются значения других полей, используя в качестве разделителей пробелы и анализируются стандартным анализатором. Т.е. если в title или description попадает фраза "черная накидка", то в _all будут токены "накидка", "черная". И ваш поисковый запрос должен находить документы 100%. Маппинг в данном случае не играет роли. Напишите пример документа, который добавлен в индекс и не находится. Я точно скажу в чем причина.

Comment: @AndreyMorozov обновил вопрос. Выложил пример документов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В _all объединяются значения других полей, используя в качестве разделителей пробелы и анализируются стандартным анализатором. Стандартный анализатор не превратит "накидки" в "накидка".  Маппинг в данном случае не играет роли.

Если записать в title "**Чехлы и накидки на сиденья**", то в **_all** попадут следующие токены **"и", "на", "накидки", "сиденья", "чехлы"**. Совпадения с "match": {"_all": "накидк**а**"} не будут найдены.

---

***Решение***

Если вы хотите использовать анализаторы, то ну нужно использовать поиск по конкретным полям, например с помощью [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) , а не по __all.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "накидка", 
      "fields": [ "title", "description" ],
      "analyzer": "my_search_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

Здесь можно настроить поиск более тонко. Еще рекомендую использовать в запросе анализатор такой же, что и при индексации. Это нужно для разбиения на одинаковые токены.

Плохая идея использовать анализатор "russian_morphology" совместно с "russian". Обычно russian урезает слова слишком сильно, как ему кажется, до корня. Нужно оставить что-то одно, скорее всего "russian_morphology". Иначе будет очень сложно разобраться почему слово превратилось в такой замысловатый токен.

Проверяем:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/categories/_analyze?analyzer=russian&pretty=true" -d 'накидки'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "накидк",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
} 


curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/categories/_analyze?analyzer=russian_morphology&pretty=true" -d 'накидки'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "накидка",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
```

Второй вариант мне нравится больше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но все же запрос с  multi_match из примера выше отдает пустой резульат:

    `{
  "took": 17,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}`

запросы с _analyze отдают тот же результат что и в ответе

Comment: Значит у вас что-то не то с маппингом. Вот рабочий пример https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5t8DmhUiBgNaDkxazkxeEdaaUE/view?usp=sharing , я только убрал анализатор russian.

Comment: спасибо за сформированный файл. К сожалению, результат тот же - пустая выборка в ответе. В индексе добавлено 2 элемента. Поиск с пустым телом выводит оба.

Можно как-то продебажить сам russian_morphology ? Убедиться в его работе как можно?

Comment: Понял. _search в файлике запрашивается через POST если сменить на get все работает. Спасибо!